# How to force user to clear cache after production in Angular 6

Tags: angular, caching

I have an external css file (work.css) and I put this file in `angular.json` to be compiled

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/work.css"
            ],
```

Now and for example, if I have `margin-left: 50px` and I changed it to `margin-left: 10px` and release a new production to users. The browser cached the 50px, and the 10px doesn't appear until I clear the cache. How can I force the user to clear cache after a new production?

**EDIT**

And the same problem appears in each component css.

Comment: If you really use `ng build --prod` to generate your application, then a new file name will be generated, precisely to avoid caching issues. So you have nothing else to do than releasing an actual production build.

Comment: what about each component css inside the application?

Comment: Same principle. Run `ng build --prod`, and you'll see that all the generated bundles have a hash in their name.

Answer (score 1):

Http caching is generally not an easy problem. Actually it is very easy as long as you know how it works :) Adding --prod to you ng build will generate the index.html file that will include all the static resources js, css with the unique indetyfier. So

```
style.css
```

will become

```
style.sdfsrregsfd32453455.css
```

Unfortunately this is just part of the story as index.html can and will be cached by the browser. And you can't change that. Hhere is another caching mechanism that can help us, it is called ETag (**E**ntity **T**ag).

Basically the http server, that is serving your website, will add to to the index.tml GET request a header that will identify that resource. Browser will send that id with each request to fetch index.html. Server will analyze it and if the index.html has not change will send response with no body. With the `302 Not Modified` code.

### [image: examle of the etag flow]

I have a longer blog post on the subject:
https://medium.com/12-developer-labors/http-caching-with-hazelcast-and-other-trics-how-to-make-my-angular-app-load-faster-aeaa90562e94

Comment: yes, you're right. so what can i do with my angular app deployment to avoid caching issue

Comment: did you find the solution for this?